# Godot How to get Colliders Parent Name (C# godot mono v3.1.2 stable)

Tags: c#, mono, collision, godot, collider

I have this code :

```
    var Collide = MoveAndCollide(new Vector2(speed.y * (float)Math.Cos(teta), speed.y * (float)Math.Sin(teta)));
    if (Collide != null)
    {
        /* I need to get colliding objects parent node name here*/
    }
```

Here is my tree hierarchy:

[image: Hyerarchy]

Red ones are objects which are colliding. Green one is which one i want to get its name in string format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself this one works :

```
    var Collide = MoveAndCollide(new Vector2(speed.y * (float)Math.Cos(teta), speed.y * (float)Math.Sin(teta)));
    //Just defined a MoveAndCollide

    if (Collide != null)
    {
        var x = (Godot.Node2D)Collide.Collider;

        //Use collider as a Godot Node or Node2D
        //then you can access Node properties and method like GetName()

        GD.PrintS(x.GetName()); // Returned speedBoost for me
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First take a look at the docs for [`KinematicBody.move_and_collide`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_kinematicbody.html#class-kinematicbody-method-move-and-collide):

> Returns a KinematicCollision, which contains information about the collision.

The docs for [`KinematicCollision`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_kinematiccollision.html#class-kinematiccollision) list a number of fields, one of which is [`collider`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_kinematiccollision.html#class-kinematiccollision-property-collider):

> The colliding body.

Note that the body is the `PhysicsBody` that owns a collision shape, *not* the collision shape itself (the latter is stored in `collider_shape`). This means that `collider` will be the `StaticBody` in your example, so we can just do:

```
    var Collide = MoveAndCollide(new Vector2(speed.y * (float)Math.Cos(teta), speed.y * (float)Math.Sin(teta)));
    if (Collide != null)
    {
        print(Collide.Collider.Name)
    }
```

Comment: I cant use Collide.Collider.Name error : Object' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'Object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)